# Forcing VPN on demand to "on"

Tags: ios, network, mobile-device-management, vpn

When we install an iOS configuration profile for Cisco IPSec "VPN on Demand" (using certificate based machine authentication), a switch appears in the Settings > VPN Settings page: "Connect On Demand ON/OFF".

We don't want to give our employees the option to turn off VPN on Demand.  Is there a way to force VPN on Demand to "ON" all the time for MDM (mobile device management) deployed configurations?

Or alternatively, is there any other way to force user traffic to a proxy under our control?

Rumour has it that iOS 6 will include Global HTTP Proxy settings.  Will enterprise IT admins be able to force this setting to "ON" all the time?

Answer (score 1):

As of iOS 11 there's still no ability to disable the on/off switch for VPN Connect on Demand, even in Supervised mode. The built-in IKEv2 VPN has an Always On setting, but that's not going to apply the Cisco or other 3rd-party VPNs.